# VB6 shell regedit import file not working

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have a .reg file in D:\ named "test.reg" (d:\test.reg)

If I go to cmd and type: regedit /s test.reg

It works...

But if I try this on VB6 it doesn't import the .reg (even if I compile the .exe and execute as admin)

```
Shell ("regedit /s d:\test.reg")
```

I'm trying to add my program to currentversion/run so it starts with Windows.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with reg and regedit, searched lots of examples and none of examples works...

Comment: Try using a class that wraps the respective Win32 API methods for registry access, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/badcodes/vb6/blob/master/%5BInclude%5D/Components/Registry.cls). I consider the Shell() method only to be the _last resort_ kinda way of doing things, if there are other/"proper" ways of doing things.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Some things you could try...  take the `/s` off and see if its running.  It could be a context refresh, depending on what's in the `.reg` file.  Perhaps it's running but the currently executing EXE (or IDE) doesn't detect the changes until restart?  I tried in various ways, including from the immediate window, from actual code (didn't bother with actually compiling), and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's best to enclose the file in quotes:

`Shell "regedit.exe /s /c " & Chr(34) & "d:\test.reg" & Chr(34), vbHide`

Comment: Or, just escape/double your quotes:  `Shell "regedit.exe /s /c ""d:\test.reg"""`